# Select or deselect all checkboxes within a ListView using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, listview

I have list view with check boxes and I want to select or deselect all check boxes on check change of check box which is out side of list view.

Previously I'm using Grid View and my code for grid view is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CheckAll(element) {
           var type = false;
           if (element.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked)
               type = true;
           var tbl = document.getElementById('<%=gdvContactDirectory.ClientID %>');
           for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
               try {
                   var el = $(tbl.rows[i]).find('input[type="checkbox"]')[0];
                   el.checked = type;
               } catch (e) { }
           }
       }
```

But after I switch to list view so now I want same functioning for list view.

my list view look like this:

```
  <asp:ListView ID="listViewContacts" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ClientIDMode="Static"
        RepeatColumns="4">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemplaceholder" runat="server" />
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="ContactDirectory ">
                <div class="Padding5">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="TableBorder2">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="BorderBottomGreen" colspan="2" valign="top">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="62%" valign="top">
                                            <span class="NormalTextBig">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("FullName")%>'></asp:Label></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="38%" valign="top" align="right" class="FontColor1">
                                            <strong>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Category")%>'></asp:Label></strong>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" align="left">
                                            <span class="NormalTextBig">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblOrganization" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:Label>
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblContactDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Address")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="AltColor22 SmallerText" colspan="2">
                                <strong>Remark</strong>:
                                <asp:Label ID="lblRemark" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Remark")%>'></asp:Label><br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" width="50%">
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfContactID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("ContactID") %>' />
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPrint" Font-Size="16" runat="server" Style="float: left" ToolTip="Select for Print" />
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" width="50%">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/delete_icon.png"
                                    ToolTip="Delete" CommandName="Delete_" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("ContactID")%>'
                                    OnClientClick="return ConfirmDelete();" Style="max-width: 16px; min-width: 16px" />
                                &nbsp;
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/Edit.png" CommandName="Edit_"
                                    ToolTip="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ContactID") %>' Style="max-width: 16px;
                                    min-width: 16px" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

If any one find the answer please put it with the code.

Comment: Can you post your listview code?

Comment: Tejsoft  i have put the list view code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you have to do:

1. Add a checkbox in the header template or outside the scope of the listview. It would be your select / deselect all checkbox. Give an unique css class (here "selectall") to this checkbox.
2. In your listbox add a css class to your checkbox (I have used "selectone").
3. Copy the following snippet of jquery script on your aspx page to select / delete checkboxes.

   ```
   $(function() {    
       // Select deselect all
       $('.selectall').click(function() {
         if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
             $('.selectone').prop('checked', true);
         } else {
             $('.selectone').prop('checked', false);
         }
     });  

     // Update select all based on individual checkbox 
     $('.selectone').click(function() {
         if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           if ($('.selectone:checked').length == $('.selectone').length) {
               $('.selectall').prop('checked', true);
               } else {
               $('.selectall').prop('checked', false);
           }          
         } else {
             $('.selectall').prop('checked', false);
         }
     });  

   });
   ```

Here is the complete example in fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/tejsoft/wdz5v1qk/5/